# Ribbon hidden after page load, shows only after selecting an item

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon

I have a SharePoint 2010 list which ribbon hides after the page loads. It only loads when I select an item. The weird thing is that even if I add `?InitialTabId=Ribbon%20%ListItem`
 to the url, it loads for a second then disappears.

Any idea how to fix that without JS code injection ?

Thanks.